# Using a TI-84 calculator to find the lowest 20% of a normal curve

Tags: probability, calculator

I am not the greatest at math, I am very confused about the second part of this problem, the problem is

> Given a normal distribution of values for which the mean is 70 and the
>   standard deviation is 4.5.  Find the probability that a value is
>   between 65 and 80 using your TI calculator.

Which I got was 0.8536

The second part of the questions is the troublesome part (for me at least) it asks

> Using the same normal curve above, determine the value for which the
>   lowest 20% of the data is under using your TI calculator

I have attached [the graph being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YljPb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment.** Six hours and no answer to what ought to be an easy question.

You are asking for the 20th percentile or quantile .2. This is found using the inverse CDF. I do not have a TI calculator at hand, but seem to recall there is a way to find inverse CDFs. From R statistical software the answer is 16.2127 because in R the normal inverse CDF function is called 'qnorm'. (This doesn't match the colored area in the picture you linked. I think that figure is for the first part of the problem.)

```
qnorm(.2, 70, 4.5)
##  66.2127
```

You can verify this is right by verifying the probability between $-\infty$ and 
 66.2127 is 0.20. Or that the probability between $-100$ and 66.2127 is o.20.

I hope this helps.

Maybe someone with a TI calculator will see this and tell you *exactly*
how to do inverse CDFs on a TI. (I edited your Question to make it easier for
the right person to find.) Also, I suppose you can google something like
`TI calculator inverse normal CDF` and get help on the Internet.

[*This Answer on our site*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868254/how-many-time-the-standard-deviation-do-i-need-to-travel-from-mean-in-both-dire/1868912#1868912) mentions an `invNORM` function on a TI-84. Maybe it will help.